# EF Code First Migration with Multiple Database / DbContext

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-migrations, multiple-databases

I have two database each with their own dbcontext. I've setup two migration configurations. I can add a migration for the first db ust fine (`Add-Migration DB1_InitialCreate -ConfigurationTypeName DB1Configuration`). When I try to create an initial migration with the second db using: `Add-Migration DB2_InitialCreate -ConfigurationTypeName DB2Configuration`, I get the following error:

> Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following explicit migrations are pending: [201205082215265_DB1_InitialCreate]. Apply the pending explicit migrations before attempting to generate a new explicit migration.

So I do what it says and update the database with:

```
Update-Database -ConfigurationTypeName DB1Configuration
```

Then I try to add a migration again for the second db but I keep getting the same error.

Any ideas on how to get migrations working for two databases/contexts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've been able to answer my own question. My two configuration classes existed in the same namespace. As soon as I separated them, everything worked.

Comment: I have two DbContexts in the same namespace, but don't get this problem. Using EF 5.0 RTM.

Comment: I also had to separate them by namespace (EF 6.x); it wasn't enough to Update-Database -ConfigurationTypeName nameOfConfiguration

Answer (score 7):

With **Entity Framework 6** it's easy.

It's the same procedure for both multiple DbContexts for one database and for multiple DbContexts for each their own database:

`Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName <DbContext-Name-with-Namespaces> -MigrationsDirectory:<Migrations-Directory-Name>`

`Add-Migration -configuration <DbContext-Migrations-Configuration-Class-with-Namespaces> <Migrations-Name>`

`Update-Database -configuration <DbContext-Migrations-Configuration-Class-with-Namespaces> -Verbose`

[Source](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/801628/Code-First-Migration-in-Multiple-DbContext)

Answer (score 5):

It's been a while, but this could be a better answer to your problem :)

```
Update-Database -ConfigurationTypeName "SlaveConfiguration"
                -StartupProjectName "FacturatieMVCv2.Data" -Verbose 
                -ConnectionString "connstring;" 
                -ConnectionProviderName "System.Data.SqlClient"
```