# Using migrations with separate contexts for regular model and Identity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-migrations

I want my Identity data context (`IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>`) and my regular EF model's data context (`DbContext`), to be separate.

Many say to merge them, but I don't see the point. They are very different, at least in my scenario, and I want to decouple them.

When I use initializers for each (CreateAlways, DropCreate, etc.), all works well. But I would like to use migrations for both data contexts - *and I can only make it work for one, not both.*

What is the secret to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible. It is necessary to set the parameters to the `enable-migrations` command, which allows more than one context per assembly, and to control each one separately.

Answer (score 0):

Does your to contexts reside in the same namespace? 
If so try to separate them into individual namespaces as suggested [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507910/ef-code-first-migration-with-multiple-database-dbcontext)