# Entity Framework 6 migrations with multiple databases

Tags: entity-framework-migrations

I have a project with 5 databases and 5 data contexts. Migrated to code first and adding migrations.

Each migration configuration is specified, however when I generate the first migration and the `__MigrationsHistory` table is created on the specific database, upon creating the second migration, I get an error

> Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following explicit migrations are pending: [202310111722593_InitialCreate]. Apply the pending explicit migrations before attempting to generate a new explicit migration.

I've researched to try and get the `__MigrationsHistory` table on a central database using info from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/history-customization)

and override configuration with

```
public PayrollDbConfiguration()
{
     AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
     MigrationsDirectory = @"Migrations\PayrollDb";
     var db = new MasterContext(Jamlite.Database.Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultCon);
     SetHistoryContextFactory("System.Data.SqlClient", (connection, defaultSchema) => new System.Data.Entity.Migrations.History.HistoryContext(db.Database.Connection, defaultSchema));
}
```

None of these approaches worked so far, not sure what I'm missing.

Ideally I'd like to get each configuration to ignore the migrations of other configurations, that was the assumption I had going in, or to have a single `__MigrationsHistory` table for all configurations

Answer (score 0):

This was somewhat of a duplicate, answer was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507910/ef-code-first-migration-with-multiple-database-dbcontext?rq=2)

Each configuration needed to be in a separate namespace with their own name, using the default name even when specifying namespace didn't work.